# Mapping a string value to an image causes, image to rendered as absolute path

Tags: reactjs, image, svg, mapping, react-tsx

How can I convert an image to a relative path,

I have used an object to map a string to an image. like this.

**flags/index.ts**

```
import ad from './ad.svg';
import ae from './ae.svg';
import af from './af.svg';
import ag from './ag.svg';
```

**ports/index.ts**

```
import portN from './nvcs.svg';
import portq from './qvcs.svg';
import portN1 from './n1vcs.svg';
```

```
const country = {
    'ad':ad, // country name
    'ae':ae, 
    'af':af, 
    'ag':ag,
    'agc':ag
}
```

```
const port = {
    'portN':portN,
    'portq':portq, 
    'lcsport':lcsport, 
}
```

then i have imported this in a another file

**Asset/index.ts**

`import flags from '../../Assets/flags';`
`import ports from '../../Assets/ports`

And getting the asset category, which is passed as prop

```
    let _assetCategory;
    const getAssetType = () => {
        if (assetCategory === 'flags') return flags;
    }
```

afterwards I get the correct image by passing the asset name which is also recieved as prop

```
{_assetCategory &&
                <img src={asset ? _assetCategory[asset] : src}
                    alt={asset ? asset : ''} data-testid="asset-img" className={`asset ${size} ${className}`} />
            }
```

Now heres the problem when I check out the image urls it shows as

```
{ad: 'static/media/src/components/Assets/flags/ad.svg', ae: 'static/media/src/components/Assets/flags/ae.svg', af: 'static/media/src/components/Assets/flags/af.svg',}
```

considering the image types depend on their category. And each image category has a huge number of images. I maybe mapping this wrong. if so is there a better way to map them, or is it possible to convert this absolute path to a relative path. Or maybe another approach which would work.